# Get description of second OU/CN

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have following script:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "z*"} -Properties * | select samaccountname, name, Email
Address,  @{Name="LastLogonTimeStamp";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp))}}, @{n='ParentContai
ner';e={$_.distinguishedname -replace '^.+?,(CN|OU.+)','$1'}} | Format-Table
```

[RESULT EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A4MF.png)

[image]

How to get description of **second** OU|CN container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $_.DistinguishedName -replace '^.+?,((CN|OU)=[^,]+).*','$1'
```

Note the trailing `.*`, which ensures that the regex matches the *entire* input string and replaces it with the substring of interest *as a whole*; without `.*`, only part of the input would be replaced, followed by whatever part of the original that didn't match.

This assumes that all components are `,`-separated (not sure why your images shows a `.` after the 2nd `OU` component) and that the CN/OU values have no *embedded, escaped* `,` instances.

You could make the inner `(...)` subexpression - whose match needn't be *captured* - slightly more efficient with `(?:...)`.